# html to Generate or update xml from file list?

Tags: javascript, html

so im making a javascript image gallery for a friend- and he wants to be able to add new images later. Right now i have javascript generate the gallery from an xml file (which is created by custom picassa export). is it possible to have the html file update the xml file with new images- it needs to be able to add a couple tags for the format and know the file name. is it possible without using php?

thanks

Comment: try studying **XSLT** http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: hmm thanks- does this require internet connection to use once i have the code setup? or can it all be run locally?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript to parse the XML file, it will update with new content when he adds it to Picassa. Don't download the Picassa XML file, you should be able to link directly to it.

Comment: i dont think he would be using picassa, its just what i was using to start the xml file- he would be just dragging images into the folder